# Java script or jquery in rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a collection select

```
<%=f.collection_select :logic, @logics, :last, :first, :prompt => true%>
```

now i have only 5 value in this drop down and on selecting different value from list i want to show different text down to this drop down

like i have span below this collection select is

```
 <td><span class="note" id="spanid1" >Select the logic type.</span></td>
```

now suppose we have 5 different value in drop down is

A,B,C,D,E

and when we select

A message in span is "this logic give you daily spend"

b message in span is "this logic will give daily saving"

c message in span is "daily profit" and so on

now how can i do this and can we change the value in same span dynamically.

Comment: Show us the rendered html and what you have tried and had problems with.

Comment: gdoron i did not understand you what you want to explain here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
var names = {
  A : "spend",
  B : "saving",
  ..and so on
};
$("#yourSelectElement").change(function() {
  //$(this).val() will have A,B,C,D or E
  var spanText = "this logic will give " + names.$(this).val();
  $(".note").html(spanText);
});
```

Comment: Thanks man its working fine for me thanks a lot for teaching me one more logic